# What is Paul's intent with "we do not wrestle against flesh and blood" in Eph. 6:12?

Tags: new-testament, ephesians, pauline-epistles

The previous question at [Are the principalities and powers in Titus 3:1 the same as in Ephesians 6:12?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/34803/are-the-principalities-and-powers-in-titus-31-the-same-as-in-ephesians-612) is about the other part of the verse.

Given the larger context in Eph. 5 & 6, dealing with human relationships, is it consistent with Paul's intent to say that, while we do struggle with people, we shouldn't look at people as the enemy, but we struggle with people deceived by the "present darkness" and people with the potential to be redeemed.

Paul's example is his witness to Festus, Felix, and Agrippa in Acts 24-26.

Comment: In short, "YES" - our primary enemy is the "roaring lion". (1 Peter 5:8)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*OP: Given the larger context in Eph. 5 & 6, dealing with human relationships, is it consistent with Paul's intent to say that, while we do struggle with people, we shouldn't look at people as the enemy, but we struggle with people deceived by the "present darkness" and people with the potential to be redeemed.*

Yes. Just like it is possible to be under the influence of the Holy Spirit (Romans 8:1-17, Galatians 5:22-26, Acts 1:8, etc.), there is plenty of scriptural evidence that people can be operating under the influence of Satan and his evil forces:

> 3 Then **Satan entered Judas**, called Iscariot, one of the Twelve. [Luke 22:3, ESV]

> 3 But Peter said, “Ananias, **why has Satan filled your heart to lie** to the Holy Spirit and to keep back for yourself part of the proceeds of the land? 4 While it remained unsold, did it not remain your own? And after it was sold, was it not at your disposal? Why is it that you have contrived this deed in your heart? You have not lied to man but to God.” [Acts 5:3-4, ESV]

> 5 And **the devil took him up and showed him all the kingdoms of the world** in a moment of time, 6 and said to him, **“To you I will give all this authority and their glory, for it has been delivered to me, and I give it to whom I will**. 7 If you, then, will worship me, it will all be yours.” [Luke 4:5-7, ESV]

> 4 In their case **the god of this world has blinded the minds of the unbelievers**, to keep them from seeing the light of the gospel of the glory of Christ, who is the image of God.[2 Corinthians 4:4, ESV]

> 8 Be sober-minded; be watchful. **Your adversary the devil prowls around like a roaring lion, seeking someone to devour**. [1 Peter 5:8, ESV]

> 44 You are of **your father the devil**, **and your will is to do your father's desires**. He was a murderer from the beginning, and does not stand in the truth, because there is no truth in him. When he lies, he speaks out of his own character, for he is a liar and the father of lies. [John 8:44, ESV]

> 2 and also some women **who had been healed of evil spirits and infirmities**: Mary, called Magdalene, **from whom seven demons had gone out**, [Luke 8:1-2, ESV]

> 28 And when he came to the other side, to the country of the Gadarenes, **two demon-possessed men** met him, coming out of the tombs, so fierce that no one could pass that way. 29 And behold, they cried out, “What have you to do with us, O Son of God? Have you come here to torment us before the time?” [Matthew 8:28-29, ESV]

> 43 “**When the unclean spirit has gone out of a person**, it passes through waterless places seeking rest, but finds none. 44 Then it says, ‘I will return to my house from which I came.’ And when it comes, it finds the house empty, swept, and put in order. 45 **Then it goes and brings with it seven other spirits more evil than itself, and they enter and dwell there, and the last state of that person is worse than the first**. So also will it be with this evil generation.” [Matthew 12:43-45, ESV]

... and many more examples.

Comment: Good answer - simple and straight forward.  Well done. +1